# Sticky header with 100vh container in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to position a sticky header with a container that occupies the remaining height using properly but it's not working properly. The header it's not sticky to the top and the container is higher than the remaining height of the screen, so you can scroll breaking it all.

I'm using the class `sticky-top` in the header and `container-fluid` for the container. Inside the container, I have a fixed left sidebar and another column occupying the remaining width of the page.

This is the pen with the code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/brWqrW

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.